# get session in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, session, session-variables

I am setting captcha string in session like below in .cs file :

```
context.Session["captchaString"] = (object)s;
```

context is object of HttpContext class.

Now I want to validate it using javascript (cliend side). For that I am using below sysntax but it gives always previous session value only, not current :

```
var captcha = '@HttpContext.Current.Session["captchaString"]';
```

In .cs file (server side), getting proper current session value. So, what is the mistake in client side? Please help me. I got stuck, not getting solution. I want to do client side validation.

Thanks.

Comment: You should never validate it using `JavaScript`..

Comment: But my requirement is to validate it before postback. Any another suggestion?

Comment: There is no point of using captcha if you are testing it using JS...You can go with the AJAX but I am not certain about security harms..

Comment: Do you realize that the variable will be whatever the value is when the page is first rendered? The JavaScript variable does not get updated as the server is updated.